# Capture Tradingview Charts with Python

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I just wanna preface this with I'm just a hobbiest and don't do this for a living, sorry if I missed any info you may need to help.

The Exchange.py file contains the code for the question!
[Link to project Github](https://github.com/pattty847/Trading-Bot/tree/main/WaveTrend%20Bot%20v1.1)

I've made a signal bot where I want to grab the corresponding ticker and chart from tradingview. I've tried to use HTML2Image and Beautifulsoup to no avail. I'm trying to copy this feature seen in another software called Alertron which gives this ability to their alerts, you can see it [here](https://alertatron.com/docs/how-to-capture-a-chart-with-your-tradingview-alerts).

I really have no idea how I can go about grabbing a component like a chart with beautifulsoup, I've only grabbed text and images.

[Here is where the chart is stored on tradingview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcg14.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.